# SOLR - Querying Facets, return N results per Facet

Tags: solr

I have a very large number of documents stored in a SOLR index. I would like to perform a query that returns the Facet counts for a specified field, and the first 100 documents for **each Facet field** returned.

For example. Let's assume I have a bunch of books stored in my SOLR index.

```
{ name: "Book 1", genre: "Mystery" },
{ name: "Book 2", genre: "Science Fiction" },
{ name: "Book 3", genre: "Romance" },
{ name: "Book 4", genre: "Mystery" }
```

Now, I want to specify a Faceted query on a field, in this example, the book's genre. `facet=true&facet.field=genre`. This search result may look something like:

```
 "facet_fields":{
    "genre":[
       "Mystery",503322,
       "Science Fiction",40759,
       "Romance",23987
    ]
 }
```

This gives me the number of books matching each genre. If I were to add a `rows` parameter to my query, this would simply return to me the first N number of books that match the query.

However, I want to go one step further. I want SOLR to return to me the **first 100 books of each genre** that match my query. This means that, since 3 facet fields were returned (Mystery, Science Fiction, and Romance), this search might return up to 300 documents.

If possible, I would like this all to be executed within a single query. Am I able to do so? Do I need to query SOLR multiple times in order to get what I am looking for? If so, what is the recommended approach to get what I am looking for?

I'm fairly new to SOLR and just trying to get a grasp on what SOLR is and isn't capable of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [group option](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) in Solr. For instance to get the first 100 documents for each `genre` you would use `group=true&group.field=genre&group.limit=100`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I want. Thank you!